# Softwares for drawing hyperbolic surfaces , closed, with boundaries or with punctures ?

Tags: soft-question, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, mathematical-software

In a paper I am in the process of writing in LaTeX, I need to draw and incorporate some diagrams of hyperbolic surfaces in my LaTeX document. Is there any software I can use to draw hyperbolic surfaces, either closed, or with boundaries or punctures ? Are there any such freely downloadable softwares that I can use to draw such diagrams ? Please let me know if you know one. I apologize if this is off-topic. Thank you !

Comment: If it is to be published in a journal, consult the web page of the journal about what they want for diagrams.

Answer (score 6):

Recently, Dani Calegargi put together a program called wireframe for this purpose. It is documented [here](http://lamington.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/wireframe-a-tool-for-drawing-surfaces/) and available [here](https://github.com/dannycalegari/wireframe). Playing around with it, it seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Try 3D-XplorMath, available for free download at http://3D-XplorMath.org . You can see many surfaces created using the program in The Virtual Math Museum at

http://virtualmathmuseum.org/Surface/gallery_o.html#AlgebraicSurfaces

Answer (score 2):

POV-Ray can make beautiful 3d plots of surfaces, but it can take a lot of work to get what you want. [Here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Ellipsoid) is an ellipsoid that I made using the method described on [Friedrich A. Lohmueller](http://www.f-lohmueller.de/pov_tut/a_geo/a_geo__e.htm)'s site. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe TikZ and PGF [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/). Also, there is a package based on TikZ, called PGFPlots, [here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/).

Another option is to use [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/): The Vector Graphics Language.